# Get intent details

Tags: android, android-intent

I made a shortcut to a chat activity, and it works fine.
The function I used is the following:

```
private void addShortcut() {
        // Adding shortcut for MainActivity
        // on Home screen
        Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(GroupChat.this, SignUp.class);
        shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
        Intent addIntent = new Intent();
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_INTENT, shortcutIntent);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME, groupName);
        addIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_ICON_RESOURCE,
                Intent.ShortcutIconResource.fromContext(GroupChat.this,
                        R.drawable.contact));
        addIntent.putExtra("duplicate", false);
        addIntent.setAction("com.android.launcher.action.INSTALL_SHORTCUT");

        GroupChat.this.sendBroadcast(addIntent);
    }
```

The problem is, that when the user click the shortcut to the chat activity, I need to know the name of the shortcut, so I can load the suitable chat acitivity. How can I do that?

Thanks in advanced! :)

Comment: just `addIntent.putExtra("name", _shortcutname_)`?

Comment: As you can see, I already put this line.. but In which function I need to add the line: "intent.getStringExtra("Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME");"?
I tried to use it inside the void sendBroadcast(Intent intent), but it returns null..

Comment: @user2320431 try this instead intent.getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME)

Comment: the activity that gets started receives the whole bundle, just call `getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME);` in the other activity

Comment: Hey diego and bleeding, it's still null.. maybe it's not the same intent?
I have tried: getIntent().getStringExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SHORTCUT_NAME);
on the "onCreate()" method

Comment: You seem to be using this intent to send a broadcast - so you want to pick it up on the other side in a BroadcastReceiver, not in the onCreate of an Activity.

Comment: Why do you need to know the name of the shortcut? I've never added launcher icons programmatically myself but would expect that it points to the activity provided in __shortcutIntent__ .

Comment: Hey @harism, I need it, beacause it's a shortcut to a chat activity. and by the shortcut's name I know which group messages to load..
(There are lots of chat groups in user app).
The answer above solved the problem! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the shortcut name to the `Intent` that will be used to start your application:

```
    Intent shortcutIntent = new Intent(GroupChat.this, SignUp.class);
    shortcutIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    // Add the shortcut name as an Extra so SignUp activity can get it
    shortcutIntent.putExtra("shortcutname", groupName);
```

in `SignUp.onCreate()` do this to get it:

```
    String shortcutname = getIntent().getStringExtra("shortcutname");
```